# different results in different environments (AWS Lambda vs Local) using the same ffmpeg command

Tags: java, android, video, lambda, ffmpeg

I am getting to my wit's end here. So I have an AWS lambda that is just some Java code that runs an ffmpeg command on a video file. When I download this video file and ffprobe it, the metadata looks different from what it looks like when I grab the same file and run the same ffmpeg command locally from the command line. I have no idea why this is. I made sure to have the same ffmpeg versions and all, but the file resulting from the lambda running the command is missing things compared to the other one. The reason I'm looking at this is the fact that this file resulting from the lambda running the command is not playable on certain players (has issues with android exoplayer and the android/mobile version of Chrome, for instance) while the one resulting from me running the command is playable everywhere that I've tried. Here are the different metadatas:

As run locally:

```
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s
```

vs as run by the lambda:

```
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s
```

As you can see, one has DAR and SAR explicitly stated next to the resolution and also has "tv" next to progressive in parentheses next to yuv420p. I've tried tweaking the command by adding more filters and flags, but the end result is the same... I'm not sure this would fix my playability issue, but could someone explay why the end results are different despite using the same version (and both are 64 bit) of ffmpeg and all?

Comment: Show the command and full console outputs.

Comment: It looks like you're omitting the profile level in the command and letting ffmpeg figure it out, try forcing it to baseline in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with android not being able to play back the video ended up being unrelated to this. It was simply because the extension of the file produced was in all caps, and android didn't really recognize it.